# iPhone Buttons Question

Tags: objective-c, ios4, interface-builder

Once I tap the button, its default highlight color is blue.  How can you change the highlight color of a button.  Either in interface builder or by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IB when you select the Button Attributes of your UIButton choose "Highlighted State Configuration" (instead of "Default State Configuration") and select an image for the Background.

Or in code: `[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`

So you rather set an image, than set a color.

You might want to look into code examples of creating your custom UIButton ([`UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`), using UIImage's `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` instance method.